# Need help in splunk regex field extraction

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a splunk query(**index=sat sourcetype="sat_logs" Message="*application message published for*"**)  which returns list of messages published by different applications.I need to extract specific field values from the messages.Please let me know the query to get the expected results. Thanks

Splunk query results:
Message:Alpha application message published for UserId: 12345678, UID: 92345678, Date: 2019-10-04, Message: {"Application":"Alpha","ID":"123"}

Message:Beta application message published for UserId: 12345670, UID: 92345670,Date: 2019-10-03, Message: {"Application":"Beta","ID":"623"}

Message:Zeta application message published for UserId: 12345677, UID: 92345677,Date: 2019-10-02, Message: {"Application":"Zeta","ID":"523"}

Expected fields to be extracted and displayed as Table

**Application    UserId         UID           ID**
Alpha          12345678       92345678      123

Beta           12345670       92345670      623

Zeta           12345677       92345677      523

Answer (score 0):

The `rex` command can do that for you.  Assuming the fields are always in the same order, this should do the job.

```
index=sat sourcetype="sat_logs" Message="application message published for"
| rex field=Message "UserId: (?<UserId>[^,]+), UID: (?<UID>[^,]+).*{"Application":"(?<Application>[^"]+)","ID":"(?<ID>[^"]+)"
| table Application UserId UID ID
```